# How C measures the time in <time.h>

Tags: c++, c, time.h

I want to be able to calculate the time using the minimum amount of header files as possible. So I looked inside of the `<time.h>` header and found the time function as,

```
extern time_t time (time_t *__timer) __THROW;
```

I kind of understand what `extern` means but I couldn't find anywhere where the body of this function is, I am not even sure if there is such thing.

So how this `time` function know what to do, and where can I find it?

Comment: It's in the standard library somewhere.

Comment: `time` is part of the standard C library. Don't know what your platform details are. [glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) is the common library for Linux.

Comment: Usually precompiled into binary libs so there's no need to include the source in your system. For example you could find it in libc.so in Ubuntu x64 by `objdump -TC /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so | grep "\<time\>"`.

Comment: @kaylum I am at ubuntu right now

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35564970/how-to-format-a-time-stamp-in-c/35565089#35565089) is a working example. Maybe will help you to get an Idea

Comment: The actual implementation of `time` is done [in the kernel](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/kernel/time/time.c#L63), so this question is more about how glibc interacts with the kernel than finding things in the source of glibc. Therefore, I don't think it is a duplicate of the mentioned question, @PP.

Comment: @Michi Thank you. Yes I saw something like that. But what I want to do is to get the current time without using `time(NULL)`. I want to be able to do what the `time` function does inside.

Comment: I'm seconding what @Sjoerd said; I believe this question is sufficiently different from the one it supposedly duplicates that it merits its own thread. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 0):

time.h is a header from the C standard library.

You can find it in your c library implementation of your system. [This](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/posix/time.c;h=2afe174788cc878f90fb2b921561972ca2d97392;hb=HEAD) is the posix implementation in glibc.

Comment: Your linked source code is a stub, did you actually read it?

Comment: I checked the link but it seems like the function always return or set the parameter `-1`.

Comment: He is right i did not check. The implementation you are looking for will be under [sysdeps](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=tree;f=sysdeps;hb=HEAD).

Comment: @aebudak Thank you for the links. I looked some code, they are included `<sys/times.h>`. Is there any link to see what is inside of `sys/times.c`?

Comment: There is no `sys/times.c`. What are you trying to find?