# How to measure execution time in C on Linux

Tags: c, linux, time, measure

I am working on encryption of realtime data. I have developed encryption and decryption algorithm. Now i want to measure the execution time of the same on Linux platform in C. How can i correctly measure it ?. I have tried it as below

```
             gettimeofday(&tv1, NULL);
         /* Algorithm Implementation Code*/
             gettimeofday(&tv2, NULL);

        Total_Runtime=(tv2.tv_usec - tv1.tv_usec) +          
                      (tv2.tv_sec - tv1.tv_sec)*1000000);
```

which gives me time in microseconds. Is it correct way of time measurement or i should use some other function? Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Too broad. Profile the code **iff** it isd too slow. It need not be faster than you data transfer.

Comment: There are lot of time measurement questions here, they are easy to find.

Comment: The elapsed time is useless on multitasking systems, call `getrusage(2)` and look at `ru_utime` (user CPU time used) instead.

Comment: Could this [Answer be what you need](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35564970/how-to-format-a-time-stamp-in-c/35565089#35565089) ?

Answer (score 4):

Read [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html). You probably want to use [clock_gettime(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html) with `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID` or 
`CLOCK_MONOTONIC`. Or you could just use [clock(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/clock.3.html) (for the CPU time in microseconds, since `CLOCK_PER_SEC` is always a million).

If you want to benchmark an entire program (executable), use [time(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html) command.

Answer (score 4):

`clock()`: The value returned is the CPU time used so far as a clock_t;

### Logic

Get CPU time at program beginning and at end. Difference is what you want.

### Code

```
#include <time.h>

/* ... */

clock_t begin = clock();

/****  code ****/

clock_t end = clock();
double time_spent = (double)(end - begin) //in microseconds
```

<sub>To get the number of seconds used,we divided the difference by `CLOCKS_PER_SEC`.</sub>

### More accurate

In C11 `timespec_get()` provides time measurement in the range of **nanoseconds**. But the accuracy is implementation defined and can vary.

Answer (score 0):

Measuring the execution time of a proper encryption code is simple although a bit tedious. The runtime of a good encryption code is independent of the quality of the input--no matter what you throw at it, it always needs the same amount of operations per chunk of input. If it doesn't you have a problem called a timing-attack.

So the only thing you need to do is to unroll all loops, count the opcodes and multiply the individual opcodes with their amount of clock-ticks to get the exact runtime. There is one problem: some CPUs have a variable amount of clock-ticks for some of their operations and you might have to change those to operations that have a fixed amount of clock-ticks. A pain in the behind, admitted.

If the single thing you want is to know if the code runs fast enough to fit into a slot of your real-time OS you can simply take to maximum and fill cases below with NOOPs (Your RTOS might have a routine for that).