# Efficient way to compare GPS timestamps

Tags: c, timestamp

My target is to compare two u_long timestamps, delivered by a GPS device. A long integer like 16290212 has the following structure:

> hhmmssµµ

The following code snippet shows an approach how to parse a long integer to an integer array. But I think this is not very efficient. What would be the quickest way to compare two timestamps? I would love to use an UNIX timestamp, but it is not possible in this context.

```
u_long timestamp_old = 16290212;

u_long base = 1000000;

/* arr[0]: hours
 * arr[1]: minutes
 * arr[2]: seconds
 * arr[3]: miliseconds */
int arr[4];
int i=0;

// parse timestamp_old
while(base >= 1)
{
    arr[i++] = (timestamp_old / base);

    timestamp_old = (timestamp_old % base);

    base /= 100;
}
```

Comment: why not just compare them?

Comment: When you say "not possible in this context", what do you mean?  I work with GPS timestamps all the time, and I do so (among other things) by converting them to something akin to a time_t, so that I can do arithmetic on them more easily.

Comment: Imagine you have a time like 03:09:52 and 03:10:03 - Just subtracting it would not give me the difference of 9 seconds. Maybe I just do not get the point

Comment: `if (gps1 > gps2) { u_long tmp = gps1; gps1 = gps2; gps2 = tmp; }`

Comment: If all you care about is comparing them to see which is greater, you can use `<` and `>`, just like usual.  It's true, though, you can't naively subtract them.  130001 - 125959 is 4042, not 2.

Comment: @SteveSummit You are right, this is the actual problem I have.

Comment: If you have a number `x` expressed as hhmmss, you can convert that to a monotonic count of seconds `s` by doing something like `s = x % 100; x /= 100; s += x % 100 * 60; x /= 100; s += x * 3600;`.

Comment: Or, if you have the GPS timestamp as a string, straight out of the NMEA message, you could use something like `sscanf(gpstimestamp, "%2d%2d%2d.%d", &h, &m, &s, &ms)`.  Then, if that succeeds, your timestamp is `(h * 60 + m) * 60 + s + ms/1000.`.  (Actually, that's not quire right for the subseconds, but you get the idea.)

Comment: In any case, I recommend doing the conversion from HHMMSS to straight seconds as early as possible.  The fact that you have an unsigned long containing hhmmssµµ suggests that someone has called `atol` or `atof` on the number in the NMEA message, which gets you into this confusing pickle, and which is therefore not necessarily a good idea. (Also, don't worry about the "efficiency" of the conversion: it's not bad, and given the structure of NMEA timestamps, there's really no way around it.)

Comment: I could avoid using atol for the NMEA message. But comparing strings is unefficient, isn't it? This was my thought.

Comment: @localhorst27 Do you want to compare, or subtract?

Comment: I want to check if the difference is smaller than 400 ms

Comment: Did you try `sscanf`?

Comment: `µµ` does not make sense to encode milliseconds.  I'd expect `µµµ` or `µµ` with tens-of-milliseconds  Which way is it?

Comment: @chux µµµ is correct.

Comment: I really stuck. I get the NMEA timestamp as a string. What would be the best way to compare them? The messages are coming in with a 10 Hz frequency. Therefore, calculating the difference has to be as quick as possible....

Comment: 1) Quickest on average or quickest on worst case? 2) Is 1 timestamp _always_ on or after the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What would be the quickest way to compare two timestamps?
>   I want to check if the difference is smaller than 400 ms

Perhaps not the *fastest* yet at least a starting point with a quick worst case.  Note that `ssµµµ` is the same as `µµµµµ`.

```
int32_t GPS_to_ms(u_long timestamp) {
  int32_t ms = timestamp%100000;
  int32_t hhmm = timestamp / 100000;
  ms +=  (hhmm%100)*60*1000;
  int32_t hh = hhmm / 100;
  ms +=  hh*60*60*1000;
  return ms;
}

if (GPS_to_ms(timestamp_later) - GPS_to_ms(timestamp_first) < 400) {
  // timestamps are in close succession.
}
```

To speed things up on *average*, 1) assume `timestamp_later >= timestamp_first` 
is usually true 2) timestamps typically have the same `hhmm`

```
bool GPS_compare_400(u_long first, u_long later) {
  int32_t ms1 = first%100000;
  int32_t hhmm1 = first/100000;
  int32_t ms2 = later%100000;
  int32_t hhmm2 = later/100000;
  if (hhmm1 == hhmm2) {
    return ms2 - ms1 < 400;
  }
  return GPS_to_ms(timestamp_later) - GPS_to_ms(timestamp_first) < 400;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your timestamps are `u_longs`; compare them the same way you compare any 2 `u_longs`, something like `<`.

Comment: Imagine you have a time like 03:09:52 and 03:10:03 - Just subtracting it would not give me the difference of 9 seconds

Comment: You didn't ask for the difference; you asked how to compare them.

Comment: @localhorst27 [Check my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35564970/how-to-format-a-time-stamp-in-c/35565089#35565089), I am sure you can adapt it to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the input is a string `gpstime` of the form "hhmmssµµµ".  I assume that trailing zeros are always present such that there are always exactly three digits for the microseconds part.

1.

```
int h, m, s, us;
double t;
if(sscanf(gpstime, "%2d%2d%2d%3d", &h, &m, &s, &us) == 4)
    t = (h * 60L + m) * 60 + s + us/1000.;
else {
    /* parse error */
    t = 0;
}
```

If that's not efficient enough, here's something down-and-dirty, eschewing `scanf`:

2.

```
#define Ctod(c) ((c) - '0')

int h = 10 * Ctod(utctime[0]) + Ctod(utctime[1]);
int m = 10 * Ctod(utctime[2]) + Ctod(utctime[3]);
int s = 10 * Ctod(utctime[4]) + Ctod(utctime[5]);
int us = 100 * Ctod(utctime[6]) + 10 * Ctod(utctime[7]) + Ctod(utctime[8]);
double t = (h * 60L + m) * 60 + s + us/1000.;
```

In either case, once you've got your `t` values, just subtract and compare as usual.

If you don't want to use floating point, change `t` to `long int`, change the scaling factors as appropriate, and compare your final difference to `400` instead of `0.4`.

(But with all of this said, I wouldn't worry about efficiency too much.  10 Hz may sound fast to a pitiful human, but a tenth of a second is a hell of a long time for a decent computer.)